# How to close menu on onclick menu item in react js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to close the menu when I click on any one of the menu items. Its working fine with button icon but not working when I click on the menu item. How can solve this issue in react js?
I am doing this using CSS property.
Please see the screenshot for reference.

On button click its working fine but not working for when I click on any one of the item.

[image]

Code:

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import Image from 'next/image'
import navbar from '/const/navbar'
import Button from '../button'
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function Navbar() {
   const [activeClass, setActiveClass] = useState(0);

   return (
      <>
         <nav>
            <input id="nav-toggle" type="checkbox" />
            <div className="logo">
            <Link href="/">
            <Image className=" cursor-pointer h-8 opacity-90" src="/workforwin-logo.png" width={172} height={44} alt="Workforwin Logo" />
            </Link>
            </div>
               <ul className="links">
                  {/* Getting nav items */}
                  {navbar.data.map((items, i) => (
                     <li className={activeClass === i ? "text-indigo-600" : "hover:text-indigo-600"} key={i} onClick={() => setActiveClass(i)}><Link href={items.link}>{items.text}</Link></li>
                  ))}
                  {/* Account Button */}
                  <Button link="" data="Account" type="" />
               </ul>
            <label htmlFor="nav-toggle" className="icon-burger">
               <div className="line"></div>
               <div className="line"></div>
               <div className="line"></div>
            </label>
         </nav>
      </>
   )
}
```

CSS:

```
nav {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0 4%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: var(--secondary);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    /* -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; */
}
nav .logo {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #e4d7d5;
    /* font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace; */
}

nav .links {
    /* float: right; */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
nav .links li {
    list-style: none;
    /* color: var(--text-primary); */
    transition-delay: .1s;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
nav .links li:hover{
  /* color: var(--text-secondary); */
  transition-delay: .1s;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
nav .links a {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    /* color: #603030; */
    text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}

#nav-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
}
nav .icon-burger {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
nav .icon-burger .line {
    width: 25px;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: var(--skyblue);
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-class{
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any code for opening or closing a menu in here

Comment: using css for that.

Comment: That's a bad practise and you shouldn't do it this way

Comment: Can you tell how can I do this same using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
//js script part
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

const openMenu = () => {
    setIsOpen(true);
}

const closeMenu = () => {
    setIsOpen(false);
}
```

```
//jsx part
<div className={ isOpen ? 'menuIcon open':'menuIcon'}>
    <ul className='navbar-list'>
        <li>
            <NavLink className="navbar-link" to='/' onClick={closeMenu}>Home</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
            <NavLink className="navbar-link" to='/about' onClick={closeMenu}>About</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
            <NavLink className="navbar-link" to='/services' onClick={closeMenu}>Services</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
            <NavLink className="navbar-link" to='/contact' onClick={closeMenu}>Contact</NavLink>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div className="mobile-navbar-btn">
        <CgMenuMotion name="menu-outline" className='mobile-nav-icon' onClick={openMenu} />
        <CgCloseR name="close-outline" className='mobile-nav-icon close-outline' onClick={closeMenu} />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).